# Pass parameter from controller to service in Angular

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I'm trying to pass a parameter from a controller to service in Angular.  Here is the controller:

```
angular.module('CityCtrl', []).controller('CityController',['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http,CityService){

  $scope.data = "unknown";

  $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
    $scope.data=data;
  });
  console.log($scope.name);
  if($scope.name){
   $scope.weather = CityService.get($scope.name);
}

     $scope.update = function (zip) {
        $scope.zip = zip;
        console.log(zip);
        $scope.weather = CityService.get({zip: zip});
        alert("Hello, " + zip);
    }
}]);
```

and here is the service:

```
angular.module('CityService', []).factory('City', '$scope'['$http', function($scope,$http) {

    return {
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/cities/' + zip);
        }
     }       
}]);
```

When I check the console it is logging the correct value, however, when it tried to run the service it says:

```
Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

For some reason the zip is not being passed to the service.  Any idea where the disconnect is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to inject `City` Service, When using explicit dependency annotation, it is *all or none* rule, you cannot just specify part of your dependencies.

```
angular.module('CityCtrl', []).controller('CityController',
        ['$scope', '$http', 'City'
 function($scope,  $http,  City){
```

Also you cannot inject `$scope` in a factory (It is available for injection only to controllers, for directive you get it as an argument in the linking function) and looks like you do not need as well.

```
angular.module('CityService', []).factory('City', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        get : function(zip) {
            return $http.get('/cities/' + zip);
        }
     }       
}]);
```

Comment: Now I'm getting "ReferenceError: zip is not defined"

Comment: Think again why do you get it? you need to pass zip to the service method right. :) Now i dont know how your api serves the purpose for `CityService.get($scope.name)` and `CityService.get({zip: zip})` which you will have to figure about.

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to write that I realized I forgot to do that. Thanks!